# How do I fix a CS0103 error for a button?

Tags: c#, button, compiler-errors

I've been working on this one for a while now. This is my first real project, so I don't know much about what I'm doing. It's my first time using this site, so if I can make anything easier to understand, tell me!

I'm trying to make this button grayed out unless you have a staff. This itself should work, the problem is I am getting a CS0103 error: `Assets\GameManager.cs(57,2): error CS0103: The name 'Button2' does not exist in the current context`

I don't know how to identify the button within the code, which I assume is the problem.

This is my code:

```
void Update()
{
    bool StaffHave = false;

    Button2.interactable = StaffHave;
}
```

Am I naming the button wrong? Do I need to be more specific and say what scene it's in or something? If so, how? I'm confused and not entirely sure what's wrong, so I can't google answers as I have no clue what to google. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So first of all, it's good to see the actual error message. Second, that doesn't look like Windows C#. Ist this by chance related to the Unity engine? Third, you can simplify that by `Button2.interactable = StaffHave` and skip the ifs. But that's not the cause of your error...

Comment: wait windows and unity c# are different?

I am using unity though

Comment: With Windows I meant Visual Studio and .NET. Unity has their own framework and just uses C# as a language. It just wasn't clear what technology you use because it differs and your code wouldn't make sense in a WinForms oder WPF project.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you. I use Unity and do my coding in notepad. I would use visual studio but my computer has a problem with the C drive always being full despite there being nothing in it, so I can't download it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to extend the class and/or adding the `using` directive on the namespace `UnityEngine.UI`.

This example should work.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    //
    // ...
    //
    void Update()
    {
        bool StaffHave = false;

        if (StaffHave == false)
        {
            Button2.interactable = false;
        }

        if (StaffHave == true)
        {
            Button2.interactable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That got rid of the error, but now it says 'Button 2' does not exist in the current context. My button is called Option2 but elsewhere in my code it is referred to as Button2 and that section is not throwing up an error.

Comment: Then please update your question accordingly, since the error stated in your question is gone. Don't ask multiple questions in one Post. See also [ask]

Comment: Thanks, I realize now that was probably an inappropriate thing to do. Should I create a new question for this error, or do I just keep it in its updated format? I've edited it to be more concise so now I'm just waiting for it to reopen.